# Macbook performance issues with browsers

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu, firefox, activity-monitor

I have a MacBook Pro from 2013, and I'm having issues in both Chrome and Firefox - both are slowing down to a crawl, and when I check Activity Monitor I have multiple processes (in all the 'tabs' at the top) slowing everything down and triggering the fan.  Now I'm guessing each add-on in Firefox and Chrome creates another process called FirefoxCP Web Content, but I also have multiple Adobe CEF Helper and Google Crome Helper.

Is there a way to prevent these multiple processes from starting up, without having to go to Activity Monitor and shut things down? Something like a 'basic' setting (like SafeMode) without a massive drain on performance?

Comment: The *FirefoxCP Web Content* is actually one of your tabs that has "run away" with CPU utilization.  Interestingly, it doesn't' happen on every website, but, one of the websites that's affected by this is `stackexchange.com`.  Kill the tab, wait a couple seconds for the process to die and then reopen.  It will (temporarily) solve it.

Comment: Each tab you have open in Firefox and Chrome creates a new process e.g.  FirefoxCP Web Content. They also take ip memory and that tends to be the real issue as it swaps and compresses. What memory pressure do you have

Comment: I just applied an update:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208937 and the problem *seems* to have been fixed.  FirefoxCP is no longer maxing out the CPU and the performance has increased greatly.

Comment: Thanks Allan - that helps to know and I'm going to try that update! Mark, this is interesting - makes the business case for only have a few tabs open then.   The memory pressure has definitely been in the red and triggering the fan.  I wish there was a way to prevent this, but at least I know what's up at least around the browsers.

Comment: Why (yes, do tell, why) don't you just use Safari? So much more efficient. So much faster. So much better battery life.